# Unable to install composer PHP version error

Tags: php

I am going to install a composer in my php project for `PHP` spreadseet, but I got a `php version` error.

I tried to install so many times but remains the same error.

this `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet",
    "description": "PHPSpreadsheet - Read, Create and Write Spreadsheet documents in PHP - Spreadsheet engine",
    "keywords": ["PHP", "OpenXML", "Excel", "xlsx", "xls", "ods", "gnumeric", "spreadsheet"],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "LGPL-2.1-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Maarten Balliauw",
            "homepage": "https://blog.maartenballiauw.be"
        },
        {
            "name": "Mark Baker",
            "homepage": "https://markbakeruk.net"
        },
        {
            "name": "Franck Lefevre",
            "homepage": "https://rootslabs.net"
        },
        {
            "name": "Erik Tilt"
        },
        {
            "name": "Adrien Crivelli"
        }
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "check": [
            "php-cs-fixer fix --ansi --dry-run --diff",
            "phpcs --report-width=200 samples/ src/ tests/ --ignore=samples/Header.php --standard=PSR2 -n",
            "phpunit --color=always"
        ],
        "fix": [
            "php-cs-fixer fix --ansi"
        ],
        "versions": [
            "phpcs --report-width=200 samples/ src/ tests/ --ignore=samples/Header.php --standard=PHPCompatibility --runtime-set testVersion 5.6- -n"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.6|^7.0",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-fileinfo": "*",
        "ext-libxml": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-SimpleXML": "*",
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "ext-xmlreader": "*",
        "ext-xmlwriter": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "ext-zlib": "*",
        "psr/simple-cache": "^1.0",
        "markbaker/complex": "^1.4",
        "markbaker/matrix": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.2",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7",
        "doctrine/instantiator": "^1.0.0",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.0",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^7.0.0",
        "jpgraph/jpgraph": "^4.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "@stable",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^8.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.3"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "mpdf/mpdf": "Option for rendering PDF with PDF Writer",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "Option for rendering PDF with PDF Writer",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "Option for rendering PDF with PDF Writer",
        "jpgraph/jpgraph": "Option for rendering charts, or including charts with PDF or HTML Writers"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\": "src/PhpSpreadsheet"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheetTests\\": "tests/PhpSpreadsheetTests"
        }
    }
}
```

These are error showing

```
- Installation request for mpdf/mpdf v7.1.6 -> satisfiable by mpdf/mpdf[v7.1.6].    
- mpdf/mpdf v7.1.6 requires php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Installation request for mpdf/mpdf v7.1.6 -> satisfiable by mpdf/mpdf[v7.1.6].
- mpdf/mpdf v7.1.6 requires php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Please help.

Comment: try to type `php -version`. You are using older php version than 5.6. Also please specify your environment and your os.

Comment: Use `"mpdf/mpdf": "^7.1",` version for `mpdf/mpd`.

Comment: I am using window , xampp server and PHP 7.3.6

Comment: I changed mpdf to 7.1 but still same error

Comment: Maybe try `^7.1.7`? That's apparently when PHP 7.3 support was added.

Comment: Other error comes out -Installation request for friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer v2.13.1 -> satisfiable by friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer[v2.13.1].

Comment: same issue aynber

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install dependencies with this command:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Or Update composer.json with following

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.2.0"
    }
}
```

Either of the above solutions will help you.